# About Euler project 8. question Where I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python

```
nums = """73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"""
b = list()
for a in nums:
    if a in "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0":
        a = int(a)
        b.append(a)



def multiply(liste):
    sums = 1
    for a in liste:
        sums *= a
    return sums

product = list()
for a in range(0,len(b)+1):
    l = b[a:a+14]
    product.append(multiply(l))
    
print(max(product))
```

I write this but it gives 70573265280 which is the incorrect answer. where I'm doing wrong?.
I'm trying to find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product

Comment: It says "Find the thirteen adjacent digits" but you are taking 14 adjacent digits.

Comment: Please see:  [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: In case you're curious after seeing the answer, this question can actually be solved as a one-liner, after modifying the input string with `nums = nums.replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '')`. Then you can call the one-liner `max(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:int(x)*int(y), num_string[i:i+13]) for i in range(len(num_string)-13))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple mistake. `b[a:a+14]` is a list of length 14, but you're asked for the largest product of *thirteen* adjacent digits.

Instead, you need `b[a:a+13]`.

Note that your code works with the given output, but in principle it could return the wrong result because it may overrun the end of the string and give you a list of shorter length. A correct version of your code iterates up to `len(b) - 12`.

Comment: wouldnt it iterate to `len(b)-13`?

Comment: @oskros `range(len(b)-12)` takes as its final value `len(b)-13`. Then `b[len(b)-13:len(b)-13+13]` is the final 13 digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in range(0,len(b)+1):
    l = b[a:a+14]
    product.append(multiply(l))
```

this should be 13 not 14

```
l = b[a:a+13]
```